# Project point cloud into depth image in python

Tags: python, numpy, point-clouds, open3d, camera-projection

I have a point cloud which is in the same coordinate system as the cameras used for capturing the image.

*I have a set of points (1000000, 3)*

*The camera extrinsic matrix Rt*

*The camera intrinsic matrix K*

*And my image (480, 640, 3)*

*near=0.05 and far=20 values as well as depth scale = 1000*

What i want to get out is my depth image for each camera frame I have.
However, i am stuck and just get some weird offset image.

I use open3d to read the point cloud file, numpy for the calculation and matplotlib for vizualization.

```
    if os.path.exists(PATH):

            # Read
            pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(PATH)
            o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
    
    point_cloud = pcd.points  # get points

    # Load intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters
    K = np.array([[fx, 0, cx],
                             [0, fy, cy],
                             [0, 0, 1]])
    extrinsics_matrix = np.load('rt.npy')  # Extrinsic matrix

    # Transform the point cloud to the world coordinates using extrinsics
    world_coords = np.dot(extrinsics_matrix[:3, :3], point_cloud.T) + extrinsics_matrix[:3, 3][:, np.newaxis]

    # Project world coordinates to 2D image coordinates using the intrinsic matrix
    homogeneous_coords = np.dot(K, world_coords)
    image_coords = homogeneous_coords[:2, :] / homogeneous_coords[2, :]

    image_coords = np.clip(image_coords, 0, np.array([640, 480])[:, np.newaxis])
```

Comment: ```world_points = np.asarray(geometry.points).transpose()
        world_points = np.append(world_points, np.ones((1, world_points.shape[1])), axis=0)
        points_in_ccs = np.matmul(extrinsic, world_points)[:3]
        points_in_ccs = points_in_ccs / points_in_ccs[2, :]
        projected_points = np.matmul(intrinsic, points_in_ccs)
        projected_points = projected_points.astype(np.int16)```

Try this code. I wont be free anytime soon to analyze the issue, but I guess issue is very minor because our code is very similar. Slight difference is in use of 4x4 extrinsic matrix.

Comment: @saurabheights thank you for you answer i will try that! if you have near and far values and depth scale how are you getting the final image?

Comment: I built this code to find where a mesh vertices should lie on image, but the mesh was very simple, only a few faces. Once I knew where It lies on image, I used opencv draw or fill methods to draw the line or color a triangle. Overall, it works fine. Have tested. My end goal was not to draw an image of pointcloud.

Comment: P.S. If you just want to project whole pointcloud to RGBD image, why not use http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.t.geometry.PointCloud.html#open3d.t.geometry.PointCloud.project_to_rgbd_image

Comment: @saurabheights because I wanted to have the projection indices

Comment: np.dot vs np.matmul. You used np.dot. LOL, when I was building my library, I made the same mistake in the beginning :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77633300/projection-issue-in-open3d-cpp/77636025#77636025