# Projection issue in open3D cpp

Tags: python, open3d

Hi im trying to recreate the project_to_rgbd tensor pointcloud function in python but for a legacy pointcloud. Basically going from a pointcloud to an rgbd image.
I have pretty much translated everything, I get no errors but the projection is shifted. To test my projection I create a random cube pointcloud, launch the visualizer and get the camera data from that. When I see it through the visualizer I see the whole cube in the middle but the result I get is this.[image]

Here is the code so you can test:

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np



class Projector:
    def __init__(self, cloud) -> None:
        self.cloud = cloud
        self.points = np.asarray(cloud.points)
        self.colors = np.asarray(cloud.colors)
        self.n = len(self.points)
    
#intri 3x3, extr 4x4
def project_to_rgbd(self,
                    width,
                    height,
                    intrinsic,
                    extrinsic,
                    depth_scale,
                    depth_max
                    ):
    depth = np.zeros((height, width, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
    color = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(0,self.n):
        point4d = np.append(self.points[i],1)
        new_point4d = np.matmul(extrinsic, point4d)
        point3d = new_point4d[:-1]
        new_point3d = np.matmul(intrinsic, point3d)
        u = int(round(new_point3d[0]))
        v = int(round(new_point3d[1]))
        zc = new_point3d[2]
        if (u < 0 or u > height-1 or v < 0 or v > width-1 or zc <= 0 or zc > depth_max):
            continue
        
        d = zc * depth_scale
        depth[u,v] = d
        color[u,v,:] = self.colors[i] * 255    

    im_color = o3d.geometry.Image(color)
    im_depth = o3d.geometry.Image(depth)
    rgbd = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(
                im_color, im_depth,depth_trunc=100.0, convert_rgb_to_intensity=False)
    return rgbd
        


points = np.random.rand(100000, 3)
colors = np.random.rand(100000, 3)
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors)


scene = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
scene.create_window()
scene.add_geometry(pcd)
scene.update_renderer()
scene.poll_events()
view_control = scene.get_view_control()
cam = view_control.convert_to_pinhole_camera_parameters()

p = Projector(pcd)
p.project_to_rgbd(cam.intrinsic.width,
                  cam.intrinsic.height,
                  cam.intrinsic.intrinsic_matrix,
                  cam.extrinsic,
                  1000,
                  10)
```

Also im using open3d 16.1 because newer versions have pointer issues in the visualizer.
Does anyone see the issue with what I wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few bugs which is causing this issue.

1. u,v corresponds to image width and height but your if check is w.r.t height and width respectively. Accordingly, it should be `depth[v, u] = d`, not `depth[u, v] = d`.
2. You forgot to normalize XYZ coordinates in camera or pixel coordinate system, i.e. - `new_point3d = new_point3d/new_point3d[2]`
3. Depth image cannot store values from 1mm to 10000mm (10 m with depth scale 1000) if the type is uint8. Use `uint16`.

Tip - Since you have added code to view pointcloud, then project pointcloud to RGBD. You should have added rgbd to pointcloud code which would have allowed you to visualize if you get back the original pointcloud or not. I have added in below code.

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np


class Projector:
    def __init__(self, cloud) -> None:
        self.cloud = cloud
        self.points = np.asarray(cloud.points)
        self.colors = np.asarray(cloud.colors)
        self.n = len(self.points)


    # intri 3x3, extr 4x4
    def project_to_rgbd(self,
                        width,
                        height,
                        intrinsic,
                        extrinsic,
                        depth_scale,
                        depth_max
                        ):
        depth = np.zeros((height, width, 1), dtype=np.uint16)
        color = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

        # The commented code here is vectorized but is missing the filtering at the end where projected points are
        # outside image bounds and depth bounds.
        # world_points = np.asarray(self.points).transpose()
        # world_points = np.append(world_points, np.ones((1, world_points.shape[1])), axis=0)
        # points_in_ccs = np.matmul(extrinsic, world_points)[:3]
        # points_in_ccs = points_in_ccs / points_in_ccs[2, :]
        # projected_points = np.matmul(intrinsic, points_in_ccs)
        # projected_points = projected_points.astype(np.int16)

        for i in range(0, self.n):
            point4d = np.append(self.points[i], 1)
            new_point4d = np.matmul(extrinsic, point4d)
            point3d = new_point4d[:-1]
            zc = point3d[2]
            new_point3d = np.matmul(intrinsic, point3d)
            new_point3d = new_point3d/new_point3d[2]
            u = int(round(new_point3d[0]))
            v = int(round(new_point3d[1]))

            # Fixed u, v checks. u should be checked for width
            if (u < 0 or u > width - 1 or v < 0 or v > height - 1 or zc <= 0 or zc > depth_max):
                continue

            d = zc * depth_scale
            depth[v, u ] = d
            color[v, u, :] = self.colors[i] * 255

        im_color = o3d.geometry.Image(color)
        im_depth = o3d.geometry.Image(depth)
        rgbd = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(
            im_color, im_depth, depth_scale=1000.0, depth_trunc=depth_max, convert_rgb_to_intensity=False)
        return rgbd


# Use unequal length, width and height. 
points = np.random.rand(30000, 3) * [1,2,3]
colors = np.random.rand(30000, 3)
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors)

scene = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
scene.create_window()
scene.add_geometry(pcd)
scene.update_renderer()
scene.poll_events()
scene.run()
view_control = scene.get_view_control()
cam = view_control.convert_to_pinhole_camera_parameters()
scene.destroy_window()

p = Projector(pcd)
rgbd = p.project_to_rgbd(cam.intrinsic.width,
                  cam.intrinsic.height,
                  cam.intrinsic.intrinsic_matrix,
                  cam.extrinsic,
                  1000,
                  10)
pcd1 = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(rgbd, intrinsic=cam.intrinsic, extrinsic=cam.extrinsic, project_valid_depth_only=True)
scene = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
scene.create_window()
scene.add_geometry(pcd1)
scene.run()
```

Comment: Additionally, I have added some code which is a bit more vectorized when computing projection. However, its missing range filtering. I will leave that as an exercise.

Comment: @wakkko - You also have option to convert legacy pointcloud to tensor pointcloud and then convert tensor rgbd image to legacy one. It should still be faster than above approach. Something like - `o3d.t.geometry.PointCloud.from_legacy(pcd).project_to_rgbd_image(cam.intrinsic.width, cam.intrinsic.height, cam.intrinsic.intrinsic_matrix, cam.extrinsic, 1000, 10)`

Comment: yes that was what I tried to do at first but I ran in several problems. I had to go with open3d 16.1 because other versions have pointer issue on the visualizer. That version I think (didn’t check for others) has a pointer issue with color in the tensor point cloud so it would work but I would lose color. So I just decided to write it myself in python.