# How to project a point cloud to a corresponding 2D image using Open3D?

Tags: python, numpy, point-clouds, open3d

I'm trying to project a point cloud onto a 2d high resolution image, but having some problems.

I'm currently using the function `cv2.projectPoints(point,R,T,camera_matrix, dist_coeffs)` which works well for the kitti dataset, as shown in this graph below
[projectpoint_kitti](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNiTe.png)

but when I do the same for the point cloud data from OSDAR23(https://data.fid-move.de/dataset/osdar23) it works rather poorly.
[projectpoint_OSDAR23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENbN4.png)
I used the same maths to do this, but the results are the same.
OSDAR23 provides image and point cloud data as well as calibration data, maybe I'm having trouble understanding calibration data?

```py
    pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud('//15_construction_vehicle_15.1//lidar//075_1631531288.599807000.pcd')
    camera_matrix = np.array([[7267.95450880415, 0, 2056.049238502414],
                              [0, 7267.95450880415, 1486.862908875167],
                              [0, 0, 1]])
    dist_coeffs = np.array([-0.0764891, -0.188057, 0, 0, 1.78279], dtype="float")

    T = np.array([0.0801578, -0.332862, 3.50982])
    q = np.array([-0.00313306, 0.0562995, 0.00482918, 0.998397])
    R = Rot.from_quat(q).as_matrix()
    # x,y,z  -> -y,-z,x
    R0 = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]])
    R = R0.dot(R2)
    Re = np.linalg.inv(R)
    Tinv = -1 * Re.dot(T)

    pointcloud = np.array(pcd.points)

    image = cv2.imread(
         "//15_construction_vehicle_15.1//rgb_highres_center//075_1631531288.600000017.png",cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    points2D_reproj = cv2.projectPoints(pointcloud, Re,
            Tinv, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs)
    points2D_reproj = points2D_reproj[0][:, 0].astype(int)

    pixel = points2D_reproj
    filter = np.where((pixel[:, 0] < 4112 ) & (pixel[:, 1] < 2504) & (pixel[:, 0] >= 0) & (pixel[:, 1] >= 0))
    pixel = pixel[filter]
    plt.scatter(pixel[:, 0], pixel[:, 1] , s=1)
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77633300/projection-issue-in-open3d-cpp/77636025#77636025. It might help. BTW, your question doesnt have enough details that would help others to answer.

Comment: hi! thx for your comment, att's my first post and I'm still learning how to add more details